# undefined method `title' when play object in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
2.1.1 :040 > post = Post.find(2)
Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
=> #<Post id: 2, title: "My second post", url: "tw.yahoo.com", description: "Oh..YA"> 
2.1.1 :041 > post.title
=> "My second post" 

2.1.1 :042 > post = Post.where(url: "www.google.com")
Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."url" = 'www.google.com'
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 1, title: "My first post", url: "www.google.com",        
description: "I sure hop this works">]> 
2.1.1 :043 > post.title
NoMethodError: undefined method `title'
```

I cannot have title when use post= Post.where(url: "www.google.com").
Is anyone knows why?

Comment: Because `where` returns `ActiveRecord::Relation`.Try `post.first.title`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Post.find(2)
```

returns a single instance

```
Post.where(...)
```

returns an array, or more precisely an ActiveRecord::Relation object. There is no `title` method there.

Try this instead

```
posts = Post.where(...)
posts.each { |post| p post.title }
```